# While loop incrementing with a wait not working

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, wait

I'm trying to increment the floor, and every time the status of the floor should change and show on the floor slowly increasing to the desired floor. But the floor just waits then jumps straight to he desired floor without me seeing it gradually increment.

Here's my code.

```
    void move(int floor) {
    while (floor > elevator.currentFloor) {
        elevator.currentFloor++;
        changeStatus(elevator);
        currentFlrLbl.setText("Current Floor: " + elevator.currentFloor);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } System.out.println("DONE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with the Thread you are sleeping. I suggest breaking up the work on a SwingWorker assuming you are using Swing. This allows your work do be done on a "worker" thread, and the GUI updates to be done on the EDT. Something like this:

```
public void move(int floor) {
        new SwingWorker<Integer, String>() {

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
                while (floor > elevator.currentFloor) {
                    elevator.currentFloor++;
                    changeStatus(elevator);
                    publish(floor);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                System.out.println("DONE");
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> list) {
                Integer value = list.get(0);
                currentFlrLbl.setText("Current Floor: " + value);
            }

        }.execute();
    }
```